# How to add color fill effect on hover in navbar? Also how to make the end of the section or div a little slant ant a small angel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used this code for my navbar :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Something Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

The above code is for simple navbar example. As I'm new to stackoverflow and have less reputation so I can't add images to my question.

Simple hover I can make using CSS but I wanted to make a hover in which if the cursor goes to any item on the navbar there is a effect like color water is filling in a glass.

Also I'm very curious about how to make the end of the section or div a little slant with some angle.

Please refer to the following link for reference:
[This the template for reference](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_54794/)  
I'm trying to make a navbar and end of a section exacty like this template.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh sorry! Next time I'll take care of that. And please answer the above questions if you can help. Thank you.

Comment: Try this link. This has many hover effects using CSS:<br> [http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/#effects](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/#effects)

Answer (score 0):

The template you refer to creates the bottom "slant" with the following CSS:

```
.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -195px; /* the height of your image */
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 195px; /* the height of your image */
  background: url(path/to/your/image.png) no-repeat 50% 0%;
}
```

Comment: This CSS contains property of image right? But what if the section only has texts and no images still we want to make the bottom slant?

Comment: I checked the green button on your answer :)